# Errors won't work with form inside Index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create an object form inside the Index view, all goes well, but when the save fails (validation error), the errors won't show on the screen as they should.

This is my link controller

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController


respond_to :html

def index
    @link = Link.new
    @links = Link.all
end

def create
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])
    flash[:notice] = "Link was found successfully." if @link.save
    respond_with(@link)
end

def show
    respond_with(@link = Link.find(params[:id]))
end

def statistics

end
end
```

And this is the form partial where the errors should show up

```
<h1>New Search</h1>
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>           

<% if @link.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ticket from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
            <% @link.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<p><b><%= f.label(:original, "URL") %></b>
<%= f.text_field :original %></p>

<p><%= f.submit('Find Link') %></p>

<% end %>
```

When I create a new object and original is valid, all goes well, but when it isn't I get:

Template is missing

Missing template links/new with {:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml]} in view paths

It seems to be asking for new when he gets the errors, but I want it to go to index, and show the errors there. I tried to respond with the snippet below but it didn't work too.

```
respond_with(@link) do |format|
            format.html { render :action => 'index'}
end
```

Also my index.html.erb, it loads the form partial and a recent partial below

```
<%= render 'form' %>

<%= render 'recent' %>
```

_recent.html.erb

```
<h1>Recent Finds</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Service</th>
    </tr>

<% @links.each do |link| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link.original %></td>
        <td><%= link.link %></td>
        <td><%= link.site %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

Any ideas about what can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it gives you an error like `Template is missing` that means when executing create action, if record is not saved, it tries to render 'new' page which does not exist.

I don't have much idea about respond_with and how can we override its behaviour for action failure, but you can write your code as below:

```
def create
  @link = Link.new(params[:link])
  if @link.save  
    flash[:notice] = "Link was found successfully." 
    respond_with(@link)
  else
   @links = Link.all
   render :action => :index
  end
end
```

And to display error messages, you can write this condition:

`<% unless @link.valid? %>

  put your content to display error messages here
<% end %>`

Comment: I get this -  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Comment: In fact when he tries to render index again it fails re-rendering the rest of the index, i'll put the details on the post

Comment: ok.. in action create if record is not saved, try to debug value of @link.errors. There should be some error messages there. If not, try putting `@link.valid?` just above the statement `render :action => :index`

Comment: ok ok sorry.. I didn't notice it. as we know When you render from an action it never goes again to a controller and just renders a page. So during rendering index page on failure, we must make sure that all required variables should be executed and passed to view. In our case, we should fetch all links again. I am editing my answer. try again

Comment: @link.valid? did nothing, so I tried puts @link.errors and on the web console the error appeared, but it seems it isn't being passed to the view...

Comment: Thaaanks it worked! I didn't need your error message, but re-setting @links did the trick, now the index is rendered with the error messages appearing correctly. Thanks Again

Comment: In fact it generated another error, whenever I put a correct url on the form, it should save, but I receive the error 'database is locked'

Comment: Can't help with that because I never get such an error. Although it persist after restarting a server also?

Comment: Fuggedaboutit, I left the rails console open, and it was blocking the database, once I closed, things when smoothly, thanks for the help

Comment: Yes there might be a different issue related to database

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if f.error_messages.blank? %>
    content when there are error messages
<% end %>
```

This is what I have done in 2.3.8

Comment: This should probably be <% if !f.error_messages.blank? %>, right?

Comment: I copied the error in the form from another, scaffolded app. but when i try do use yours with the block content i get NoMethod errors or error_messages

Answer (score 0):

Your `create` method responds with the your object constructed from the params regardless of whether the save was successful or not. You probably wants something like this instead:

```
def create
  @link = Link.new(params[:link]
  if @link.save
    respond_with(@link, :notice => "Yay!")
  else
    redirect_to(links_path, :alert => "Nay!")
  end
end
```

Comment: It didn't work. When it fails, it redirects to the index page silently. The problem is I want classical form errors, where all the problems appear above the form. That way it should pop up an alert right?

Comment: You need to render whatever is in your flash[:alert] in the index view. See here http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionController/Redirecting:redirect_to